# Nivo Slider in IE7

Tags: drupal, nivo-slider

I have implemented the "Nivo Slider" in my drupal site. it is working fine in all browsers. but in case of IE it is creating problem. when i refresh the page while loading the page it goes up to top portion of the site after blinking it then goes back to its original position.
here is the link of my site http://demo3.vinspro.org/. click on my portfolio in IE . then you will see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in the latest version of the slider. Download here:

http://nivo.dev7studios.com/pricing/